# Why do NULL left outer joins stop dataset navigation in PHP with sqlsrv_fetch_array?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join

I'm in the process of converting over a ColdFusion site to PHP and have hit a snag with LEFT OUTER JOINs and perhaps the PHP SQL drivers. Basically it appears that if you left outer join a table which returns no results then try to loop over the master table, it will stop when it hits the first null join result in the dataset.

Using

PHP 5.3.27, php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll, SQL Server 2005

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IS_MAIN_TABLE](
    [iMainRow] [int] NULL,
    [sMainText] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [iSubRowID] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IS_SUB_TABLE](
    [iSubRow] [int] NULL,
    [sSubText] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO IS_MAIN_TABLE(iMainRow,sMainText,iSubRowID) VALUES (1,'One',1);
INSERT INTO IS_MAIN_TABLE(iMainRow,sMainText,iSubRowID) VALUES (2,'Two',NULL);
INSERT INTO IS_MAIN_TABLE(iMainRow,sMainText,iSubRowID) VALUES (3,'Three',3);
INSERT INTO IS_MAIN_TABLE(iMainRow,sMainText,iSubRowID) VALUES (4,'Four',NULL);
INSERT INTO IS_MAIN_TABLE(iMainRow,sMainText,iSubRowID) VALUES (5,'Five',5);

INSERT INTO IS_SUB_TABLE(iSubRow,sSubText) VALUES (1,'Sub One');
INSERT INTO IS_SUB_TABLE(iSubRow,sSubText) VALUES (2,'Sub Two');
INSERT INTO IS_SUB_TABLE(iSubRow,sSubText) VALUES (3,'Sub Three');
INSERT INTO IS_SUB_TABLE(iSubRow,sSubText) VALUES (4,'Sub Four');
INSERT INTO IS_SUB_TABLE(iSubRow,sSubText) VALUES (5,'Sub Five');
```

Now running this select with a join in Studio provides the following result with 5 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM IS_MAIN_TABLE LEFT OUTER JOIN IS_SUB_TABLE ON IS_SUB_TABLE.iSubRow = IS_MAIN_TABLE.iSubRowID;

1   One    1    1    Sub One
2   Two    NULL NULL NULL
3   Three  3    3    Sub Three
4   Four   NULL NULL NULL
5   Five   5    5    Sub Five
```

Then running this PHP code for the same SQL Statement:

```
<?php

function get_error() {
  $errors = sqlsrv_errors();
  $errtxt = "Error occured: ";
  foreach( $errors as $error) {
    $errtxt .= $error["SQLSTATE"] . ", ";
    $errtxt .= $error["code"] . ", ";
    $errtxt .= $error["message"] . "<br>";
  }
  return $errtxt;
}

$sitedbserver = "SERVERHERE";
$sitedbuser = "userhere";
$sitedbpassword = "pwdhere";
$sitedbinstance = "INSTANCEHERE";
$sitedbconnection = array( "Database"=>$sitedbinstance, "UID"=>$sitedbuser, "PWD"=>$sitedbpassword);

$dbhandle = sqlsrv_connect($sitedbserver, $sitedbconnection) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");
if(!$dbhandle) {
  echo 'Database connection failed...'; 
  exit;
} else {
  //do something
}

$sql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT * FROM IS_MAIN_TABLE LEFT OUTER JOIN IS_SUB_TABLE ON IS_SUB_TABLE.iSubRow = IS_MAIN_TABLE.iSubRowID;
EOSQL;

$result = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $sql,array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
$numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

if ($numRows <> 0) {   
  echo '<table id="simplegrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">'; 
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // if($row===false){ die(get_error()); }
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['sMainText'] . '</td><td>' . $row['sSubText'] . '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>'; 
}

?>
```

I only get the first row.

```
One    Sub One
```

If I alter the SQL to exclude the NULLs...

```
$sql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT * FROM IS_MAIN_TABLE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IS_SUB_TABLE ON IS_SUB_TABLE.iSubRow = IS_MAIN_TABLE.iSubRowID 
WHERE iSubRow IS NOT NULL; 
EOSQL;
```

I get the three rows

```
One    Sub One
Three  Sub Three
Five   Sub Five
```

Uncommenting the get_error call in the loop only returns a '0' in the first row only scenario which isn't alot of help. I would expect the results to actually be the same as running the query in analyzer/studio but no dice. I have situations where the joined table will be null and that creates a condition in processing letting someone know onscreen that data is missing, etc... so I have to find a way to handle this but I'm just stumped at this point. I'm not sure if doing a coalesce on the potential null fields to '' is worth the hassle or if there is a way to get nulls to default to '' at the PHP, Driver, SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I am not looking forward to the retool of all of my existing queries but it appears that using PDO and the PDO drivers handles the null joined tables correctly. Using the same tables/data above but with this code against php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll ...

```
try{
  $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$sitedbserver ; Database=$sitedbinstance", "$sitedbuser", "$sitedbpassword");
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e){
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}

$tsql = <<<EOSQL
SELECT * FROM IS_MAIN_TABLE 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IS_SUB_TABLE ON IS_SUB_TABLE.iSubRow = IS_MAIN_TABLE.iSubRowID; 
EOSQL;

$getProducts = $conn->prepare($tsql);
$getProducts->execute();
$products = $getProducts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$productCount = count($products);
if($productCount > 0){
  echo '<table id="simplegrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">'; 
  foreach( $products as $row ){
     echo '<tr><td>' . $row['sMainText'] . '</td><td>' . $row['sSubText'] . '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';   
}
```

I get the expected response:

```
One     Sub One
Two 
Three   Sub Three
Four    
Five    Sub Five
```

I guess I shouldn't care why the non-PDO solution doesn't work now that I have a solution but if somebody happens upon this and can shed light on the reason I'd appreciate the closure.